# How to delete AWS s3 partitions and update new files into each partition using snowflake

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have folders in AWS s3 partitioned by date. How can I remove/delete the files present in these folders and add new files from snowflake table into respective partitions?

Comment: Are you leveraging external tables for this?  I'm curious as to the details of what you are trying to do with S3 and Snowflake.  Can you provide more detail?